# How to convert character string with as.Date but display as dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: r, dataframe, date, dplyr, as.date

My apologies, I cant seem to find the solution to this seemingly basic question.

This

```
p %>% mutate(date = as.Date(mr_daterd,  format = '%d/%m/%Y'), mr_daterd = mr_daterd)
```

Gives

```
     mr_daterd       date
1  28/03/2013  2013-03-28
2   10/01/2009 2009-01-10
3   16/09/2005 2005-09-16
4  28/03/2013  2013-03-28
5  28/03/2013  2013-03-28
6  28/03/2013  2013-03-28
```

I need `p$date` to be `dd/mm/yyyy`.

```
p <- structure(list(mr_daterd = c("18/03/2011", "10/01/2009", "10/01/2009", 
"11/03/2004", "10/01/2009", "18/03/2011", "16/09/2005", "10/01/2009", 
"18/03/2011", "10/01/2009", "18/03/2011", "18/03/2011", "28/03/2013 ", 
"28/03/2013 ", "10/01/2009")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try this: `p %>% mutate(date = as.Date(mr_daterd,  format = '%d/%m/%Y'),
             mr_daterd = mr_daterd,date2=format(date,'%d/%m/%Y'))`

Comment: Also see `date2`, which constains the style you want. Dates in `R` are stored as `year-month-day`, if you want to change it, you have to use `format()`.

Comment: Thank you @Duck. It seems that I have to do two steps in your solution: first creating `date=as.Date..` and then afterwards create `date2=format..` from `date` - isn't there a solution that does what I request in one line? I tried `date=format(as.Date(mr_daterd,  format = '%d/%m/%Y'),'%d/%m/%Y')` but that did not do it.

Comment: Maybe try this `p %>% mutate(date=format(as.Date(mr_daterd,  format = '%d/%m/%Y'),'%d-%m-%Y'))`

Comment: cmirian, your dates are already in the "dd/mm/yyyy" format. If you want them as actual date objects in R, these are stored and displayed in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. When you use `format` you convert them back to characters. If you need to display dates in a certain way for a certain output, you do that as the "last thing" after processing your dates.

Comment: I see. But how do I store the character dates `dd/mm/yyyy` as actual date objects but keeping them displayed as `dd/mm`yyyy` and not `yyyy-mm-dd`?

Comment: @cmirian That is the point, you can only have dates as y-m-d. If you want other style you need to transform them using `format()` and storing as characters!

Comment: There is a workaround - creating an S3 class. See my answer.

Comment: Thank you both, I learned from that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want is to create your own S3 class. This isn't as difficult as it sounds, requiring only two lines of code:

```r
as.myDate <- function(x, ...) `class<-`(as.Date(x, ...), c("myDate", "Date"))
format.myDate <- function(x, ...) format(`class<-`(x, "Date"), "%d/%m/%Y")
```

This then allows you to do:

```
p$date <- as.myDate(p$mr_daterd, format = "%d/%m/%Y")

p
#>      mr_daterd       date
#> 1   18/03/2011 18/03/2011
#> 2   10/01/2009 10/01/2009
#> 3   10/01/2009 10/01/2009
#> 4   11/03/2004 11/03/2004
#> 5   10/01/2009 10/01/2009
#> 6   18/03/2011 18/03/2011
#> 7   16/09/2005 16/09/2005
#> 8   10/01/2009 10/01/2009
#> 9   18/03/2011 18/03/2011
#> 10  10/01/2009 10/01/2009
#> 11  18/03/2011 18/03/2011
#> 12  18/03/2011 18/03/2011
#> 13 28/03/2013  28/03/2013
#> 14 28/03/2013  28/03/2013
#> 15  10/01/2009 10/01/2009
```

This new class inherits all other generic functions from "Date" so will still behave the same as a Date object:

```r
difftime(p$date[2], p$date[1])
#> Time difference of -797 days

plot(p$date, rnorm(15))
```

[image]